# React крашится при обработке события onChange на элементе input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть "поисковая строка" которая представляет из себя обычный input с событием onChange, во время которого на сервер отправляется запрос через axios, получаем список найденных результатов в виде json и потом формируем сам список с подсказками.

Проблема в том что при вводе, удаления слова из input реакт крашится и все компоненты стираются, остается белый экран.

У меня не получилось повторить ошибку так, чтобы реакт прямо написал, что ошибка возникает при установке состояния. Но она возникает при установке состояния:

```
if(this.state.isMounted){
            this.setState({
                hints: renderedHints
            });
        }
```

Также хром сообщал об утечки памяти. Пробовал сделать трюк с isMounted, но ошибка все равно возникает.

```
class SocialControl extends React.Component{

    //isMounted = false;
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            social: props.social,
            isMounted: false,
            groupMembersCount: false
        };

        //...
        this.showHints = this.showHints.bind(this);
        //перепривязываем контекст методов
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //this.isMounted = true;
        this.setState({
            isMounted: true
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        //this.isMounted = false;
        this.setState({
            isMounted: false
        })
    }

    async getHints(q){
        let groupName = q;

        return axios.get(`/api/vk/group/searchGroupByName?q=${groupName}`)
            .then( response => {
                return response.data;
            })
            .then(json => {
                return json;
            });
    }

    getGroupInfo(groupId){
        return axios.get('/api/vk/group/getInfo?id=' + groupId)
            .then( response => {
                return response.data
            })
            .then( data => {
                return data[0];
            });
    }

    renderHints(hints){

        let output = hints.map(hint => {
            return(<li key={hint.id} data-id={hint.id}>{hint.name}</li>)
        });

        return output;
    }

    hideHints(){
            let hintsBlock = document.querySelector(`.social-control__${this.state.social} .social-control__offers`);
            let list = hintsBlock.querySelector('ul');
            list.innerHTML = '';
            hintsBlock.style.display = 'none';
    }

    async showHints(e){
        let groupName = e.target.value;

        let hints = await this.getHints(groupName);
        let renderedHints = this.renderHints(hints);
        if(this.state.isMounted){
            this.setState({
                hints: renderedHints
            });
        }

        let hintsBlock = document.querySelector(`.social-control__${this.state.social} .social-control__offers`);

        hintsBlock.style.display = 'block';
    }

    render(){
        const hints = this.state.hints;

        const membersCount = this.state.groupMembersCount;
        let outputMembersCount = "";
        if(membersCount){
            outputMembersCount = `Подписчиков: ${this.state.groupMembersCount}`;
        }
        return(
            <div className={`social-control__${this.state.social}`}>
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/vk-1.svg" alt=""/>
                <div className="social-control__form">
                    <span className="social-control__name">{this.state.groupName}</span>
                    <div className="social-control__data">
                        <span className="social-control__members-count">
                            &nbsp;{outputMembersCount}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text"
                           onChange={this.showHints}
                            onBlur={this.hideHints}/>
                    <div className="social-control__offers">
                        <ul>
                            {this.state.hints}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте написать `response.data()`

Comment: Всё довольно просто, данные приходят асинхронно, получается данные в state ещё не пришли, а render уже пошёл. И он не находит данные в state, попробуйте добавить или дефолтные значения или проверку `(данные ? засунуть в state: пока ничего не делать)` или можно попробовать использовать хухи, такие как useMemo, он проверяет данные и если они поменялись переписывает state, но я хз как поведёт себя с промисами)